# Trying to program a python discord bot that bans all users. The bot only bans people without a role?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code:

```
 import discord

TOKEN = "{Removed for safety}"      # Put your Bot token here
SKIP_BOTS = False
fetch_offline_members = True

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in!')
    for member in client.get_all_members():
        if member.bot and SKIP_BOTS:
            continue
        try:
            await member.ban(reason="Banned by BanBot", delete_message_days=7)
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name}!")
        except:
            print(f"Could not ban {member.display_name}")
    print("Banning is complete!")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

The bot has admin, and a high role too, so I don't understand why it won't ban people with a role.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot must have the highest role possible on your server in order to ban all users.
This seems like a short answer but it is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tag hierarchy so you might wanna move the bots tag to the top.

[image: Tag at the bottom]
[image: Tag at the top]